# Show that $3$ is a quadratic residue mod $23$ but not mod $31$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that $3$ is a quadratic residue mod $23$ but not mod $31$.

My classmate tells me that the fact that $3^{11} \equiv 1 \mod 23$ is proof that $a$ is a quadratic residue of $\mod 23$. But, I do not understand why we use $11$?

Comment: $11 = \frac {23 - 1}{2}$

Comment: So, then if we calculate $3^{15} \mod 31$ (since $15=\frac{31-1}{2}$) then we get $30$, which is not 1 which proves that $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $31$, due to the Legendre symbol definition; is this correct?

Comment: Euler's Criterion.

Comment: Also $7^2\equiv3\pmod{23}$ shows that $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $23.$